# Nodejs express Knex select

Tags: javascript, nodejs, knex

hola amigos quiero hacer un select a mi base de datos usando **knex** , pero tengo esta situación, quiero mandar varios objetos, en este caso el primero que quiero mandar son los **owners** , lo que normalmente hago es hacer mi query y en la respuesta mando directo el response con el objeto que quiero mandar. algo así ...

```
  const query = knex().select('*').from('USERS_').where('owner',[1]);
  const owners = [];
  query.then((data)=>{

    data.forEach((data) => {
      owners.push(data);

      res.render('projects/add-project',{owners});
    });
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  });
```

Pero esta vez quiero hacer varios queries y ya hechos mandarlos en mi response, solo que no se como hacerlo con  **knex** , entonces me figuro algo así más o menos

```
router.get('/add-project', (req, res) => {
  const query = knex().select('*').from('USERS_').where('owner',[1]);
  const owners = 
  query.then((data)=>{

    data.forEach((data) => {
      owners.push(data);

      return owners;
    });
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  });

  const otroquery = ... ;

  const otroquery = ... ;

  console.log(owners);
  res.render('projects/add-project'{misqueries,otroquery,....});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rawrdríguez.Ophanim,

Para realizar lo que buscas puedes hacerlo de dos formas (basándome en tu caso):

- Promise.all

  ```
  router.get('/add-project', (req, res) => {
      const owners = []
      const promises = []

      const query1 = knex().select('*').from('USERS_').where('owner',[1]);
      promises.push(query1)

      const query2 = .....
      promises.push(query2)

      const query3 = .....
      promises.push(query2)

      Promise.all(promises)
         .then(([query1,query2,query2]) =>{
             //Aqui tendrias las tres promises/queries resueltas para trabajar con ellas

            res.render('projects/add-project'{misqueries,otroquery,....});
      })
     .catch(err => console.log(err.mnessage))
  })
  ```
- Async / Await

  ```
  router.get('/add-project', async (req, res) => {
      try{

       const query1 = await knex().select('*').from('USERS_').where('owner',[1]);
       const owners = []

       const query2 = await .....

       const query3 = await .....

       //Aqui tendrias las tres queries resueltas como variables para trabajar con ellas

       res.render('projects/add-project'{misqueries,otroquery,....});

      }catch(e){
         console.log(e.message)
      }
  })
  ```

Espero que con esta info puedas resolver tus dudas.

Un saludo